# How to get function names from compiled Python module without importing it?

Tags: python

I'm creating an intellisense type module, where you input python code and output a dictionary of function and variable names, etc. Using `import` would execute any top-level statements in the code so I would rather not use that. Instead I'm using the `ast` module. It works for .py modules but not .pyc or .so modules because `ast.parse()` actually compiles the code and the .so is already compiled. So is there a way to grab the function and variable names and docstrings from a compiled module without using `import`?

[Edited for clarity]

```
# re module is .py
import ast, imp
file_object, module_path, description = imp.find_module('re')
src = file_object.read()
tree = ast.parse(source=src, filename=module_path, mode='exec')
for node in tree.body:
    print node

# datetime module is .so
file_object, module_path, description = imp.find_module('datetime')
src = file_object.read()
tree = ast.parse(source=src, filename=module_path, mode='exec')
for node in tree.body:
    print node


 File "test_ast.py", line 12, in <module>
   tree = ast.parse(source=src, filename=module_path, mode='exec')
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse
   return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
TypeError: compile() expected string without null bytes
```

Comment: Functions have `__doc__` and `__name__` attributes for that. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#types-and-members as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The function objects don't exist unless you run the code, though, and running the code is something we want to avoid.

Comment: @user2357112: For C extensions, you have no other option. Komodo's CodeIntel used separate datafiles generated from a module to provide it with autocompletion metadata for C extensions, for example.

Comment: @user2357112: see https://community.activestate.com/faq/codeintel-cix-schema and https://community.activestate.com/faq/generate-python-api-catalog for inspiration.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: if you want to turn your second comment into an answer, I'll accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Done, with a little elaboration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C extensions, you have no other option but to import them and use introspection.

Komodo's CodeIntel used separate datafiles generated from a module (using introspection) or otherwise written manually to provide it with autocompletion metadata for C extensions, for example. Their autocompleter then uses this static data instead.

The CodeIntel project is Open Source code; see http://community.activestate.com/faq/codeintel-cix-schema and http://community.activestate.com/faq/generate-python-api-catalog for inspiration, and / or study [the source code of the toolset](http://svn.openkomodo.com/openkomodo/browse/openkomodo/trunk/src/codeintel/support).